# gear design.improving gear strength

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, gears

For improving the gear strength, which one is better based on manufacture and economy? Increasing module or increasing N? With the same surface strength.

Comment: I appreciate English may not be your primary language, but I am having difficulty understanding the question. Which aspect of gear strength do you want to improve? What is "module" & what is "N"? What do you mean by "surface strength"?

Comment: im sorry for mistakes,consider this...i wanna design a gear with a known power and rpm,i wanna choose a module(diameter/number of teeth) with module assumed 4 and number of teeth assumed 19 for example....considering surface strength and bending stress in root stress equations give you two modules...which one is economically better...increasing the module to bigger one or increasing the number of teeth(we cant increase  Sut of gears)